# Why is this loop through facebook posts not working?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm playing around with the Facebook API in Javascript to try and pull posts from Facebook. I copied code from [this page in the documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) The function will access the page given and actually produce a response. But, response.length and response[i] are returning as "undefined" thus making it impossible for the loop to work. Why is this happening?

```
<button onclick="ShowMyPosts()">Show posts</button>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ShowMyPosts() {
        FB.api('/TheWalkingDeadAMC/posts', { limit: 3 }, function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.length)
          for (var i=0, l=response.length; i<l; i++) {
                var post = response[i];
                console.log(post)
                if (post.message) {
                    console.log('Message: ' + post.message);
                } else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name) {
              console.log('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
            }
          }
  }
)
console.log("successfully ran function")        
};
</script>
```

How I get an access token. Is this incorrect?

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
        console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }{scope: 'read_stream'} 
    });
```

Comment: You need an access token to access page posts. Make sure you've followed each step of this [How to get started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/) tutorial.

Comment: I am getting an access token...I have edited it into the post. Is it incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query the Graph API - most results will be inside `data` key...

Using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) you can test your call and see what is the result without having to write a single line of code.

This is a [direct link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=TheWalkingDeadAMC/posts) to your Graph API call test. as you can see `data` holds the posts.

So, you need to loop through `response.data` and not `response`.

The code should look like this:

```
function ShowMyPosts() {
    FB.api('/TheWalkingDeadAMC/posts', { limit: 3 }, function(response) {
       console.log(response.data);
       console.log(response.data.length)
       for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
          var post = response.data[i];
          console.log(post)
          if (post.message) {
             console.log('Message: ' + post.message);
          } else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name) {
             console.log('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
          }
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was that my FB.login was incorrect. This is the correct code below:

```
FB.login(
function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
        console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }},
    {scope: 'read_stream'}  
    );
```